# CSS 100vh is too tall on mobile due to browser UI

Tags: css

What is the best way to solve this issue. Obviously all browsers on mobile have got a UI (address bar etc) at the top. This adds additional height to the viewport, so my website which is using 100vh is missing a section.

I'd assume different browsers have different sized viewports due to this, I could simply do something like `height: calc(100vh - 50px)` or what ever the height is, but it won't match up on all mobile browsers right?

Comment: Wow, I had no idea `vh` was this problematic on mobile devices. https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Usually the `100vh` height will account for the adjusted height, with is why you'll sometimes see mobile pages go funky when the browser's address bar slides down.

For browsers that don't account for the sliding bar within the `vh` unit: The height for the address bars will not be constant across the browsers, so I'd advise against appending `-50px`.

Try setting the height of the page (using javascript) with the `window.innerheight` property.

```
function resetHeight(){
    // reset the body height to that of the inner browser
    document.body.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
}
// reset the height whenever the window's resized
window.addEventListener("resize", resetHeight);
// called to initially set the height.
resetHeight();
```

Comment: A little suggestion. I would declare `body` as a `const`.
So in my case I did it this way:
```function resetHeight() { const body = document.getElementById('main-wrap')   body.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px'},
```
And then I called this function on `mounted` lifecycle hook. I think it's somewhat about `window.onload` in vanilla js.

Comment: This works great -- but it only registers when I resize my browser or open my dev tools. I am using Chrome....

Answer (score 11):

In modern browsers, you can use the [`dvh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) unit, which refers to the dynamic viewport. For more information on these new units, see the relevant [can I use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_length_viewport_percentage_units_dynamic) and [web.dev article](https://web.dev/viewport-units/).

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I had to make two adjustments:

- use document.body.style.height instead of document.body.height
- add 'px' to the end of window.innerHeight

  document.body.style.height = `${window.innerHeight}px`;

Comment: probably because you had a CSS height already, which would override the HTML height. What you did was override that CSS

Answer (score 4):

Use `height: 100%` which gives you the height after reducing the menu bar's height.

You can test the difference between `100vh` and `100%` by using `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].scrollHeight` on mobile browser.

For me (Chrome on Andriod), `100vh` returns a higher value than `100%`, which always giving me a vertical scrollbar, even if I haven't added anything in the html body.

Comment: ? Please leave a comment after downvoting.

Comment: The entire chain from html over body &c. must have height: 100%, while with 100vh you can make any child element that size. Whoever voted you down obviously tried it without the whole chain set to height: 100% and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If the element is a *direct* child of `body`, you can achieve the desired effect with:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#screenheight {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="screenheight"></div>
<p>Random content after screenheight element.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

`max-height: dvh;`

or

`max-height: -webkit-fill-available;`

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution worth mentioning...

Continue to set the height of your element to 100vh, then just declare that element's `max-height` in js.

```
$('.top-hero-container').css('max-height', (window.innerHeight + "px"));
```

Now on page load, your element will be no larger than that declared max-height, so will display fine on mobile. It obviously doesn't account for resizing, but the load overhead is less.