# Jquery variable using window.innerHeight comes back as undefined

Tags: jquery, css, undefined

I'm trying to set the height of a div based on the width of the window. `vh` units won't because of the iOS mobile issue. I'm basing my code off this related Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43575432, which works as expected, continuously updating the body height. For some reason, whenever I try to apply that to another element (*.nav-main*), the console returns *undefined*.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function resetHeight(){
      var bodyheight = window.innerheight;
      console.log({bodyheight})
      $('.nav-main').css({ 'width': bodyheight + 'px' });
    }
    
    // reset the height whenever the window's resized
    window.addEventListener("resize", resetHeight);
    
    // called to initially set the height.
    resetHeight();

});
```

Comment: Case sensitive innerHeight

Comment: Another remark - the answer, you've linked, is 3 years old - I'd suggest to use vh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a typo on the window property.

Try
`window.innerHeight`