# How to find the true viewport height?

Tags: html, css

I have html content generated by php, which is designed to fit the height of the screen. To do this, I scale the content in the style spec according to `vh`.

This works nicely on a desktop PC, but the actual target is a mobile or cell phone, and the two browsers I have tried (Samsung and Chrome) steal some of the `vh` for their own header and footer.

This defeats my purpose: that the whole content can be seen without scrolling. Yes, you can scroll the header out of the way to expand the page, but I have a sequence of generated pages and this boringly defeats the object.

The amount isn't predictable. For 20 equal lines of text, 20 are shown on the Windows desktop with Firefox, and anywhere between about 16.5 and 18.5 lines on the Android screens, until you stroke it, and the amount also varies between portrait and landscape orientation.

Here is some example code to illustrate

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vh;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: black;
  height: 5vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.p1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.p2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<p class='p2'>1 pQHMAlldFRVc
<p class='p1'>2 GBkNDXfFzsTj
<p class='p2'>3 RPgrnVsMCSYq
<!-- skip lines 4 to 18 -->
<p class='p2'>19 ZBWbDuFKRrEM
<p class='p1'>20 DyJEHsQoiiFo
```

Is there a way in CSS styling to get the true height of the viewport **after** the system has stolen some of it? The alternative is to design the pages deliberately short, but as the amount isn't consistent between browsers, the guesswork wastes space, and might not be enough for a browser I haven't yet tried.

Comment: I think what you're asking about is this: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4329 and this: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6113. So not yet, but it's being worked on.

Comment: @Alohci thank you for showing I am not mad. The desktop Windows PC approaches this the other way round – the overhead is **not included** in `vh` and you can typically use `F11` key to get a full screen view. If you would like to post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For *Safari on iOS* there seems to be `-webkit-fill-available` which should give You the height of the viewport without browser UI that can be scrolled away.

See: https://allthingssmitty.com/2020/05/11/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/

As [Alohci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42585/alohci) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67567198/how-to-find-the-true-viewport-height#comment119428917_67567198) already pointed out a solution for all browsers seems to be in the works.

If JavaScript is an option You could use the value of `window.innerHeight` which gives You the current height available. There are many possibilities how to make us of this. Here are 2 examples for You:

1. Set `window.innerHeight` as `height` and use `display: grid` for `<body>` + leave out `height` in Your `p` selector (every paragraph will have the same fraction of the grid's height = 5%)
2. Set Your `p` selector height to a 20th of `window.innerHeight`

Maybe this site is also helpful to You: https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I do actually use a mix of CSS, PHP and JS to generate the html code, to take advantage of browser cache for included files to minimize the network traffic, but without caching the content. The thing is, a change in orientation is catered for by CSS (not shown here), but Javascript only calculates once unless I further complicate it by having the JS detect the change in orientation. I'd like to keep it as simple and as portable as possible, subject to decisions as to what needs to be server-side and what can be client-side.

Comment: You're welcome.
I can't imagine a server-side solution unless You somehow had the value of `window.innerHeight` in the web request (cookies or GET/POST parameters).
It would be enough to listen to the "resize" event on the  client-side that would also handle the change in orientation.
This could be as simple as:

```js

function resetHeight(){
  window.document.body.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
}
window.addEventListener("resize", resetHeight);
resetHeight();

```
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43575432/10273301